# Place Order not working For Website Store Magento2.4.6

Tags: php, magento, magento2.4, php-8.2

The Magento version is 2.4.6. While placing an order getting below error.

`Order saving error: Deprecated Functionality: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated in vendor\magento\zend-db\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php on line 1044`

The str_replace() function has been modified, but it is still not working.

We set up the website store through `config.php` and  whenever a customer tries to place an order through that website store, a `payment-information` rest API request encounters an error.

Comment: It's very hard to debug code we can't see. Rather than just telling us that something "has been modified", please show us the code, and what specifically you've modified. Ideally, do some debugging, and create a [mre].

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue

Comment: The website store was created wrongly. Re-create store from Magento backend and its resolved.